# Google_Service_Exception error 500 not caught

Tags: symfony, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google api client to get a list of blogger posts (see below code).

```
try {

        // create service and get data
        $blogger = new \Google_Service_Blogger($this->client);

        // https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list
        // GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts

        if ($this->cache->contains('posts')) {
            $posts = $this->cache->fetch('posts');
        }
        else {
            $posts = $blogger->posts->listPosts($this->bloggerId, $optParams);
            $this->cache->save('posts', $posts, 600); // 600 = 10 mins
        }

        return $posts;


        } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
        // Error from the API.
        //print 'There was an API error : ' . $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //print 'There was a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This works fine on most occasions, but occasionally I get an API error which is not caught.

```
Google_Service_Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8894809254783984374/posts?maxResults=5: (500) Backend Error at /var/www/releases/20140607051057/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79)"} []
```

Does anyone know why this error is thrown, and how I can deal with it?

Cheers

Comment: If I remember correctly 500 is normally a server hiccup, wait a few seconds and try again.  I normally try 3 or 4 times before I let it fail.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but what I need to know is how to catch the error 500 so that my page does not break. the try catch I have in place does not seem to work.

Comment: your }'s seam to be a little confusing to me.   What exactly does it print when it fails.

Comment: Did you forget the `use Exception` statement at the top of your file ?

Comment: Ah yes you mean `use \Exception` ? do I also need one for apiServiceException ? I can't find this exception in the google api client code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with the namespaces. You can use the generic:

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //print 'There was a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

or, more specific:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e) {
  //print 'There was a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Exception is the base class for all Exceptions. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php